# grails set belongsTo nullable

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I would like to create one-to-many association with the possibility of set association to null

Exemple :

```
class Basket {      
    Long id     
    String name
    static hasMany = [
        products: ProductOrdered,
        menus: MenuOrdered
    ]
    static constraints = {
        products nullable: true
        menus nullable: true
    }
}

class Product {
    Long id
    String name
}

class Menu {
    Long id
    String name
    static belongsTo = [Product]
    static hasMany = [products: Product, menuOrdereds: MenuOrdered]
}

class ProductOrdered {
    Long id
    String name
    Product product
    static belongsTo = [
        basket: Basket, 
        menu: MenuOrdered
    ]
    static contraints = {
        basket nullable: true
        menu nullable: true
    }
}

class MenuOrdered {
    Long id
    String name
    static belongsTo = [
        basket: Basket, 
        menu: Menu
    ]
    static hasMany = [
        products: ProductOrdered
    ]
}
```

In a controller

```
    Product p1 = new Product(name: "p1")
    p1.save flush: true, failOnError: true

    ProductOrdered po1 = new ProductOrdered(name: "po1", product: p1)

    Basket b1 = new Basket(name: "b1")
    b1.addToProducts(po1)
    b1.save flush: true, failOnError: true
```

A basket may have menus and/or products
A product can belong to menu or not
A menu has many products

The probleme there is a stackstrace when I save objects
Need your help

Exemple with a Basket with one Product and one ProductOrdered (without a menu)

GORM does not let me save if productOrdered.menu == null
In Mysql tables, ProductOrdered.menu is not nullable. Event if I change it to nullable, it's not works

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
|Loading Grails 2.4.4
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
...........
|Compiling 3 source files
.........................
|Running Grails application
| Error 2015-02-18 08:40:59,750 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table menu_ordered drop constraint FK_i4w4vjts6hwiu2g878ps0nlun if exists
| Error 2015-02-18 08:40:59,754 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Table "MENU_ORDERED" not found; SQL statement:
alter table menu_ordered drop constraint FK_i4w4vjts6hwiu2g878ps0nlun if exists [42102-176]
| Error 2015-02-18 08:40:59,761 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table menu_ordered drop constraint FK_e5s9ouao2g6s177von7l1q179 if exists
| Error 2015-02-18 08:40:59,761 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Table "MENU_ORDERED" not found; SQL statement:
alter table menu_ordered drop constraint FK_e5s9ouao2g6s177von7l1q179 if exists [42102-176]
| Error 2015-02-18 08:40:59,762 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table menu_product drop constraint FK_3x0fpyo630osfevs0ft7f1a71 if exists
| Error 2015-02-18 08:40:59,763 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Table "MENU_PRODUCT" not found; SQL statement:
alter table menu_product drop constraint FK_3x0fpyo630osfevs0ft7f1a71 if exists [42102-176]
| Error 2015-02-18 08:40:59,763 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table menu_product drop constraint FK_d2m4dwlin0lqvfomlddca3esn if exists
| Error 2015-02-18 08:40:59,764 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Table "MENU_PRODUCT" not found; SQL statement:
alter table menu_product drop constraint FK_d2m4dwlin0lqvfomlddca3esn if exists [42102-176]
| Error 2015-02-18 08:40:59,764 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table product_ordered drop constraint FK_8s3qhvlniylmc2d46db1h2yy0 if exists
| Error 2015-02-18 08:40:59,765 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Table "PRODUCT_ORDERED" not found; SQL statement:
alter table product_ordered drop constraint FK_8s3qhvlniylmc2d46db1h2yy0 if exists [42102-176]
| Error 2015-02-18 08:40:59,765 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table product_ordered drop constraint FK_lw8nr4nw9a30x79f1yvdq5n1i if exists
| Error 2015-02-18 08:40:59,766 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Table "PRODUCT_ORDERED" not found; SQL statement:
alter table product_ordered drop constraint FK_lw8nr4nw9a30x79f1yvdq5n1i if exists [42102-176]
| Error 2015-02-18 08:40:59,766 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table product_ordered drop constraint FK_kcarly7tnj0en6ro0n78ues2n if exists
| Error 2015-02-18 08:40:59,766 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Table "PRODUCT_ORDERED" not found; SQL statement:
alter table product_ordered drop constraint FK_kcarly7tnj0en6ro0n78ues2n if exists [42102-176]
|Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/a
| Error 2015-02-18 08:41:22,731 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - ValidationException occurred when processing request: [GET] /a/test/index
Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 'order.Basket' on field 'products[0].menus': rejected value [null]; codes [order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.error.order.Basket.products[0].menus,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.error.order.Basket.products.menus,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.error.products[0].menus,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.error.products.menus,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.error.menus,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.error.order.MenuOrdered,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.error,productOrdered.menus.nullable.error.order.Basket.products[0].menus,productOrdered.menus.nullable.error.order.Basket.products.menus,productOrdered.menus.nullable.error.products[0].menus,productOrdered.menus.nullable.error.products.menus,productOrdered.menus.nullable.error.menus,productOrdered.menus.nullable.error.order.MenuOrdered,productOrdered.menus.nullable.error,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.order.Basket.products[0].menus,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.order.Basket.products.menus,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.products[0].menus,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.products.menus,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.menus,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.order.MenuOrdered,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable,productOrdered.menus.nullable.order.Basket.products[0].menus,productOrdered.menus.nullable.order.Basket.products.menus,productOrdered.menus.nullable.products[0].menus,productOrdered.menus.nullable.products.menus,productOrdered.menus.nullable.menus,productOrdered.menus.nullable.order.MenuOrdered,productOrdered.menus.nullable,nullable.order.Basket.products[0].menus,nullable.order.Basket.products.menus,nullable.products[0].menus,nullable.products.menus,nullable.menus,nullable.order.MenuOrdered,nullable]; arguments [menus,class order.ProductOrdered]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]
. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 'order.Basket' on field 'products[0].menus': rejected value [null]; codes [order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.error.order.Basket.products[0].menus,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.error.order.Basket.products.menus,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.error.products[0].menus,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.error.products.menus,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.error.menus,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.error.order.MenuOrdered,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.error,productOrdered.menus.nullable.error.order.Basket.products[0].menus,productOrdered.menus.nullable.error.order.Basket.products.menus,productOrdered.menus.nullable.error.products[0].menus,productOrdered.menus.nullable.error.products.menus,productOrdered.menus.nullable.error.menus,productOrdered.menus.nullable.error.order.MenuOrdered,productOrdered.menus.nullable.error,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.order.Basket.products[0].menus,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.order.Basket.products.menus,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.products[0].menus,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.products.menus,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.menus,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable.order.MenuOrdered,order.ProductOrdered.menus.nullable,productOrdered.menus.nullable.order.Basket.products[0].menus,productOrdered.menus.nullable.order.Basket.products.menus,productOrdered.menus.nullable.products[0].menus,productOrdered.menus.nullable.products.menus,productOrdered.menus.nullable.menus,productOrdered.menus.nullable.order.MenuOrdered,productOrdered.menus.nullable,nullable.order.Basket.products[0].menus,nullable.order.Basket.products.menus,nullable.products[0].menus,nullable.products.menus,nullable.menus,nullable.order.MenuOrdered,nullable]; arguments [menus,class order.ProductOrdered]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]
    Line | Method
->>  190 | doInvokeInternal                in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractSavePersistentMethod

---

|     68 | invoke                          in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod
|    195 | save . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormInstanceApi
|     -1 | save                            in order.Basket
|     45 | defaultCall . . . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray
|    108 | call                            in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite
|    116 | call . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     18 | index                           in test.TestController
|     -2 | invoke0 . . . . . . . . . . . . in sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl
|     62 | invoke                          in     ''
|     43 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
|    483 | invoke                          in java.lang.reflect.Method
|   1270 | jlrMethodInvoke . . . . . . . . in org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor
|    154 | invoke                          in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.MixedGrailsControllerHelper
|    375 | handleAction . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper
|    252 | executeAction                   in     ''
|    205 | handleURI . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    126 | handleURI                       in     ''
|     72 | handleRequest . . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController
|     50 | handle                          in org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter
|    347 | doDispatch . . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet
|    870 | doService                       in org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
|    961 | processRequest . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet
|    852 | doGet                           in     ''
|    620 | service . . . . . . . . . . . . in javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
|    837 | service                         in org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet
|    727 | service . . . . . . . . . . . . in javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
|    303 | internalDoFilter                in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     52 | doFilter                        in org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    198 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter                        in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|    344 | invokeDelegate . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
|    261 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    101 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter                in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    101 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    101 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter                in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    748 | invoke                          in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher
|    486 | processRequest . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    411 | doForward                       in     ''
|    338 | forward . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    178 | forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils
|    144 | forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo in     ''
|    135 | forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo in     ''
|    216 | doFilterInternal . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter
|    107 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                        in     ''
|     69 | doFilterInternal . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter
|    107 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                        in     ''
|     67 | doFilterInternal . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter
|    107 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                        in     ''
|     88 | doFilterInternal . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
|    107 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    344 | invokeDelegate . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
|    261 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    220 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
|    122 | invoke                          in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve
|    171 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve
|    103 | invoke                          in org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve
|    116 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve
|    408 | service                         in org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter
|   1070 | process . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor
|    611 | process                         in org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler
|    314 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor
|   1142 | runWorker                       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|     61 | run                             in org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable
^    745 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread

Comment: How are you creating your objects?  Here id is not required to put in the domain this is by default generated by gorm.

Comment: Can you please post your controller and service code?

Comment: Did you try to use hasOne=[]

Comment: finally I found a solution by removing menu: MenuOrdered from ProductOrdered and by create ProductMenuOrdered